Outline Position in pool game
I'm developing a pool game using SFML and Box2D, and I'm currently facing an issue with creating the cue ball outline when the player aims. I have three rays that are cast: two black ones and one white one. How can I determine the position of the outline of the cue ball using the shortest of these rays as the player aims. I am using the ray cast function of box2d.
I have attached picture of the outline for further reference


Have you considered using b2World_CircleCast to cast the circle shape directly, rather than trying to imitate this with multiple rays? This will stop the circle wherever any part of its perimeter hits a collision shape, and tell you the location of that contact / the depth the circle was able to traverse.

That seems way easier. I'll definitely give it a go. Thanks for the feedback.

It may even be better for performance. When I've benchmarked it in the past, shape casts were roughly the same cost as two raycasts, so going from three raycasts to one circlecast may be a net savings. I'm not familiar enough with Box2D to write a full code sample as an answer, but if you get it working please post your own answer to help future readers.

It appears that Box2D currently does not support shape casting functionalities like circle casts or other shape casts, as the existing casting features are related to rays. According to a GitHub issue i found circle cast, capsule cast and box cast are planned for inclusion in Box2D version 3.0.
github link

That's odd — I see it defined in box2d.h as documented here — are you using an older version?

Ya am using version 2.4.1 which is the current latest version on box2d repo. where can i find version 3.0.0

Looks like version 3 is under development here - it's currently "alpha" and so may not be fully stable yet.
